# Threading with Network Connection slow on some computers and fast on others

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, imap

I have a C# program that connects to an IMAP server and downloads emails.  This program is threaded and runs very fast on one computer and very slow on another.  The slow one acts like the first thread is locking and the rest are having to wait.  The completions jump in groups of 5 witch is how many threads there are.  The fast one goes through 125 messages in about 20 seconds.

Both are
- Always on the same subnet
- Connecting to the same server
- Running the same code
- Same laptop hardware with the same OS
- 64-bit Windows 7 (service pack 1)
- .NET 3.5
- Compiled with VS 2010 Express

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated I have been beating my head against this all day.

Comment: Without knowing more about the technology you are using to connect to the server, perhaps try comparing the Internet Explorer proxy settings on each.  I've found that turning off proxy detection can sometimes speed up some types of network operations, but this depends on the APIs you are using.  I know your question has nothing to do with Internet Explorer, but the IE proxy settings are used by many apps and libraries.

Comment: I am using System.Net.Sockets to connect to an Exchange Server.  Thanks for the the tip I will check out the IE proxy settings.

Comment: Other things to think about: Does 1 machine have anti-virus and the other not? Do they both have the same ethernet card? I've had one machine run very slowly because the ethernet interface was not configured for full duplex communication, for example.

Comment: +1 for 'Does 1 machine have anti-virus and the other not?'. Performance test spec: ' 1) Turn off kaspersky...'

Comment: Both boxes have the same anti-virus running (Sophos) and I have tried turning it off to no effect.

Comment: Compare your running processes on each machine - unless they are 100% cloned images, I'd bet there's at least some differential, and that can easily change the thread handling.

Answer (score 0):

Check if dos ping command is taking too long at the "slow" machine.
Seems like Lan connectivity issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the network connection speed by putting a large file, say about a hundreds of megabytes on the imap server.

then try to download it either with browser (i'd recommended something beside IE), or standard windows file transfer (SMB/CIFS). Try it one machine at a time. And make sure that the network aren't busy while you're testing it.

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your program in Debug mode on both the computers then Build it And use the Release .exe file or run your program in non debugging mode. It will perform as it have to.